# My Items are different sized in Windows 3D printer that they are in Blender

Tags: scale, 3d-printing

So my parents are celebrating 40 years of marriage (ruby anniversary) this year. And recently I started using Blender. I have made a project that I wish I could 3D print. (The idea is that the objects in the project would be put on a wall). I set my size in the dimension tab of Blender. But when I export the items as STL. To other programs my objects are smaller that mm. I’ve tried a few things, but nothing seems to work. So, If any of you guys would take the time of your day to help I would be really grateful.

The project file is attached.
I want to make 4x doves (2 facing each side), 2x rings, 2 crystals and the numbers 4 and 1

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V8FTNHoIwsrGBXPJTaOBG2hM_YKKUmpR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: STL does not include built in units. It is as plain as that, and I wish I could give you more help. May be a professional on the subject would have a workaround idea?

Comment: Just to add to @TheLabCat, none of your objects have the scale applied. They're all way below 1. No idea whether this will make any difference in this case, but select them all in Object mode and then CTRL-A > Apply Scale to them.

Comment: Ty for all your replies. My fix was just to scale the objects in Blender by *100 so they appeared the right size then in 3D printing softwares.